# how does one buffer a direct neural interface and still benefit from real time information flow?

Tags: science-based, computers, nanotechnology

For various reason it is not "safe' to "go" mind to mind (via headset ,nanotech...or both) with another even if the Tele- Operator has been trained to disarray the various signals the Tele-Operator is sent ...as thought rarely is a linear process...and thus can only be directed toward another for moments at a time...If a brain computer interface runs in tandem with a direct neural interface as buffer...one is not really having a Rea Time communication with another...unless there are mutually agreed upon  signal catagoricals that both agree to censor...in my experience only an imbued signal that "mandates" another's cognitions and perceptions only toward a mood/mode of gamesmanship...can one be attenuated to co conscious "play"

Comment: What? I don't have a clue what you are asking?

Comment: @Jim Bloom: you seem to have an ethics question regarding a highly specific science fiction device.  You seem to have a very detailed view on how it should operate, but you have found a limit you wish to overcome.  If you could walk us through the problem, we could help better.  For example "in my experience only an imbued signal..." implies you have developed a very deep understanding of the product, but it would help if you portrayed that understanding slowly so that we can catch up.

Comment: @Jim Bloom I can see that thought is rarely a linear process... especially in this OP.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab at it.

As I understand it, you think that two people can't go mind-to-mind because thoughts aren't linear and veer off in all sorts of directions - and thus "real-time" meetings won't work out 'well' (for some categories of 'well').

You've proposed a computer to mediate, but think that this means it's no longer 'real-time' communication.

If your computers are fast enough, you won't notice (too much).  Right now, we don't notice light-speed delays when we talk to a person from around the world on the phone, nor for network slow-downs for skyping.

I suspect the same would be in effect if a really fast computer were moderating / censoring / tailoring thought threads when sharing them with another.  Even though you probably would start to notice lightspeed effects, and could only interface with someone near you (physical location).

Also, I suspect that your brain would have to drop threads of off-topicness from someone else, as we can't even manage our own threads when we think.  So losing some - by not getting them presented by a computer censor - would not be a burden, and might even be a benefit by keeping things on-topic, or not-too-immersive.